# woocommerce display last purchase and cross sells current user

Tags: woocommerce, fetch

I use specific thank you pages depend of product
I want to display the last purchase (product's name) of the current user on this page and fetch cross sell of the specific product too.

Any help would be apreciate

OF course i made some research and found tutorial like this one 
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/#comment-703884

But i am not enaugh good at php to modify it for my needs

Thank you

Comment: I find answer for display last purchase of current user thank to the help of Kirby on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362162/woocommerce-display-purchased-items-only

I need to display cross sells of this specific product now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 50 last purchased product for example, go to *function.php* in Appearance>Editor>function.php then past the code below:

```
// Recently Sold Products shortcode for WooCommerce

  add_shortcode('sold_products', 'sold_products');
  function sold_products($attributes) {
    global $wpdb, $woocommerce;
    $defaults = array('max_products' => 50, 'title' => "Last purchased");
    $parameters = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $attributes);
    $max = absint($parameters['max_products']);  // number of products to show
    $title = sanitize_text_field($parameters['title']);
    $html = '<div class="sold_products">'.PHP_EOL;  
    if ($title) {
      $html .= '<h3>Last purchased:</h3>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'woocommerce_order_items';
    $my_query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `order_item_type`='line_item' ORDER BY `order_id` DESC LIMIT %d", $max);  
    $nr_rows = $wpdb->query($my_query);
    if (!$nr_rows) {
      $html .= '<p>Aucun produit n\'est acheté encore!</p>';
    } else {
      $html .= '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
      for ($offset = 0; $offset < $nr_rows; $offset++) {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $user_info = wp_get_current_user();
    }
        $row = $wpdb->get_row($my_query, OBJECT, $offset);
        $product_name = $row->order_item_name;
        $product = get_page_by_title($product_name, OBJECT, 'product');
        $url = get_permalink($product->ID);
        $order_id = $row->order_id;
        $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
        $user = $order->get_user();
        if ($user) {
          $user_id = $user->ID;
        } else {
          $user_id = 'Guest';
        }
    if($user_info->ID == $user_id){
            $unix_date = strtotime($order->order_date);
            $date = date('d/m/y', $unix_date);
            $html .= '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'.$product_name.'</a> acheté le '.$date.'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
      }
      $html .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $html .= '</div>'.PHP_EOL;
    return $html;
  } // end function
```

you can dislay this result anywhere in your pages just past this shotcode where you want it to be displayed:

```
[sold_products max_products="50" title="Last purchased"]
```